# mongodb endpoint server error when trying to retrieve all documents but not when retrieving one document in collection

Tags: mongodb, api, endpoint, atlas

I have created the following function in mongodb atlas:

```
// This function is the endpoint's request handler.
exports = function({ query, headers, body}, response) {
    // Data can be extracted from the request as follows:
    const docs = context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("tennisRankings")
    .collection("UTR14Female")
    .find({utr: {$exists:true}})
    .toArray();
    return docs
};
```

This is paired up with an Mongo Atlas endpoint. I receive the following error when I request:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
vary: Origin
x-appservices-request-id: 6467707e967219ab3bf8ce7e
x-envoy-max-retries: 0
x-frame-options: DENY
date: Fri, 19 May 2023 12:50:06 GMT
content-length: 189
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 164
server: mdbws
connection: close

{
  "error": "error processing request",
  "error_code": "InternalServerError",
  "link": "https://realm.mongodb.com/groups/64620fa04a4f24495a3299fd/apps/6466ca1190b5521afdd68636/logs?co_id=6467707e967219ab3bf8ce7e"
}
```

However, when I change the `find()` to `findOne()`,  I retrieve the first record successfully. The working code is below:

```
// This function is the endpoint's request handler.
exports = function({ query, headers, body}, response) {
    // Data can be extracted from the request as follows:
    const docs = context.services
    .get("mongodb-atlas")
    .db("tennisRankings")
    .collection("UTR14Female")
    .findOne()
    return docs;
};
```

I have also tried:

```
.find({})
```

The linked error log output is below:

```
Error:


failed to set response

{
  "name": "getUTR",
  "arguments": [
    {
      "query": {},
      "headers": {
        "X-Cluster-Client-Ip": [
          "114.77.49.60"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
          "https"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-Client-Cert": [
          "By=spiffe://xgen-prod/ns/baas-prod/sa/baas-main;Hash=c68c5aa61293af7317ce95a81111deb355d7f6acdfabeb775e95a468d14f947a;Subject=\"O=MongoDB\\, Inc.,CN=lb-b\";URI=spiffe://xgen-prod/ns/vm-prod/sa/lb-b"
        ],
        "X-Forwarded-For": [
          "114.77.49.60"
        ],
        "X-Envoy-External-Address": [
          "114.77.49.60"
        ],
        "X-Request-Id": [
          "f0453022-268c-448d-8056-72b54252fce4"
        ],
        "Postman-Token": [
          "8c57ce45-12c6-47bf-a476-c5588c9d29ff"
        ]
      }
    },
    {}
  ]
}
Function Call Location:

AU

Endpoint Query Arguments:

{}
Endpoint Headers:

{
  "X-Forwarded-Proto": [
    "https"
  ],
  "X-Forwarded-Client-Cert": [
    "By=spiffe://xgen-prod/ns/baas-prod/sa/baas-main;Hash=c68c5aa61293af7317ce95a81111deb355d7f6acdfabeb775e95a468d14f947a;Subject=\"O=MongoDB\\, Inc.,CN=lb-b\";URI=spiffe://xgen-prod/ns/vm-prod/sa/lb-b"
  ],
  "X-Forwarded-For": [
    "114.77.49.60"
  ],
  "X-Envoy-External-Address": [
    "114.77.49.60"
  ],
  "X-Request-Id": [
    "f0453022-268c-448d-8056-72b54252fce4"
  ],
  "Postman-Token": [
    "8c57ce45-12c6-47bf-a476-c5588c9d29ff"
  ],
  "X-Cluster-Client-Ip": [
    "114.77.49.60"
  ]
}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in the linked logs?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have updated the question with the error logs

Comment: well, the logs don't tell much. Can you enable profiler on db side and check the query there? Essentially there is not enough information in the question to advise anything. 500 is a generic serverside error. It can be that query took too long to retrieve all items. It can be memory limit to hydrate all items to json. You will need to debug. Or experiment with .limit() to retrieve 10, 100, 1000 items and see where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks Alex. There are only 25 records in the document set. I added limit() and it seems to break at anything greater than 10 records returned. When I test the same query using the realm test feature, there are no issues.